# Bootstrap-datetimepicker not woking in IE8?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, datetimepicker

Im using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), but unfortunately the date picker does not working in IE8, and all other higher version working properly.

How can I fix it in IE8?

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- for bootstrap calendar -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/es-shims/es5-shim/master/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: see: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Extras/

Comment: @TamilSelvan isn't that for IE7?

Comment: is any error in console or which jquery version you used

Comment: Im using jquery 1.11.2 @TamilSelvan

Comment: The error console says "Object doesn't support property or method 'reduce' ... (bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js, Line: 8, Column: 20319)."

Comment: ok can you call this js `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/es-shims/es5-shim/master/es5-shim.min.js` after the jquery library called. and tell if issue still exist or not

Comment: What version of the datetimepicker are you using? The newest version doesn't work at [all with that version of jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/814/)

Comment: Also used jquery migrate plugin for older IE `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js`

Comment: I have using datetimepicker-  version : 4.7.14 . @wahwahwah

Comment: the issue still exist @TamilSelvan

Comment: Now is any error in console

Comment: yes..same issue "Object doesn't support property or method 'reduce'".

Comment: Can you post the html code, which order you call js and form of datapicker

Comment: Question edited..please have a look. @TamilSelvan

Comment: call `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/es-shims/es5-shim/master/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>` after jquery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75566/discussion-between-tamil-selvan-and-krish).

Comment: Not working :( ..error console says same as above ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 $(function() {
   $(document).click(function(e){
        var target = $(e.target);
        if(target.parents('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').length < 1 && !target.hasClass('datetimepickerInput') && !target.hasClass('datepickerIcon') && !target.hasClass('clockpickerIcon')){
            if($('.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget').length > 0){
                $('#startDate').data('DateTimePicker').hide();
                $('#startTime').data('DateTimePicker').hide();
                $('.datetimepickerInput').blur();
            }
        }
    });
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.1.1/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- for bootstrap calendar -->

<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working..same error..and a warning is occured that "Script from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/es-shims/es5-shim/master/es5-shim.min.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch".

Comment: @Krish Can you run the above answer in IE8 and let me know.

Comment: See the order of js library and this error  "Object doesn't support property or method 'reduce' " belong to ES5 shim

Comment: hi @selvan..i was used old version of ES5shim, that's why not working here, now just updated to 4.1.1,then it's working..Btw thank you so much for your efforts .

Comment: The calendar months navigation and the current date are not working...why?

Comment: is any error in console. sorry i using Ubuntu OS. so i guess only the what error is. not tested it.

Comment: Use latest bootstrap datepicker and test it and let me know

Comment: i have using latest datetimepicker js